# Spring Security work well when runtime, but got error while ddoing gradle build

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've been make WebSecurity like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final Environment environment;
    private final UsersService usersService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(Environment environment, UsersService usersService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.usersService = usersService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(usersService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/**")
            .hasIpAddress(environment.getProperty("app.gateway-ip"))
            .and()
            .addFilter(authenticateUser());
    }

    private AuthenticationFilter authenticateUser() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(environment, usersService, authenticationManager());
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(environment.getProperty("app.auth.login.url-path"));

        return authenticationFilter;
    }
}
```

and an AuthenticationFilter like this:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final Environment environment;
    private final UsersService usersService;

    public AuthenticationFilter(Environment environment, UsersService usersService, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.usersService = usersService;
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            LoginRequestModel credentials = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequestModel.class);

            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    credentials.getEmail(),
                    credentials.getPassword(),
                    new ArrayList<>()
                )
            );

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String username = ((User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        UserDto userDetails = usersService.getUserDetailsByEmail(username);

        String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(userDetails.getUserId())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("app.auth.token.expiration-time"))))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, environment.getProperty("app.auth.token.secret"))
            .compact();

        response.addHeader("token", token);
        response.addHeader("userId", userDetails.getUserId());
    }
}
```

It all can work well in runtime, but when I tried to build it, the build failed because the test is error. When I try to run the test, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pattern cannot be null or empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
```

**My test class only contain this code:**

```
@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

What I've done:

- I've done adding some jaxb dependencies, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

In your application you call

```java
authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(
    environment.getProperty("app.auth.login.url-path")
);
```

Your build environment does not have the property `app.auth.login.url-path`.
The Framework tries to create an `AntPathRequestMatcher` with the patter provided but the pattern is empty because the property does not exist.

Comment: Yes, it's true... It's my fault... I start using spring cloud config-server and cut all my app-properties in user-service into config-server app-properties, so it then get an error.